# Quantum Simulation Of Tunneling in Small System

Tags: simulation, universal-gates

how a single Pauli z-gate (on particular qubit) on the highest order qubit realize square well potential?
How upon acting same gate on the second highest qubit, realize double square well potential?
Can you provide some physical intuition and mathematics regarding this?
This question is regarding paper by Andrew T. Sornborger titled 'Quantum Simulation Of Tunneling in Small System ',  https://www.nature.com/articles/srep00597 .